# WinRT Using a shared resources xaml file in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I created a Universal Windows App Store app in Visual Studio 2013. I created a `ResourceDictionary` file called `AllButtonShapes.xaml`. In the Shared portion of my app, the `App.xaml` file has this in it:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AllButtonShapes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the Windows portion of the app, this works just fine and my app is able to find the resources defined in `AllButtonShapes.xaml`. However, when I try to launch the Windows Phone portion of the app, those resources aren't found.

How do I get the Windows Phone portion of my Universal app to see the resources defined in my App resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the absolute path

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/AllButtonShapes.xaml"/>
```

Honestly, I couldn't reproduce this problem. You can try checking the dictionary's build action, it must be set to `Page`. Maybe there's a name conflict or something else. Can you share your project file?

Comment: Weird. I just created a new project and it worked in that one. Hm, I guess something must be wrong with my project file. That's ok, this is a testing project where I can get things worked out. I plan on creating a new project and copying over code once I've got things into a proper arrangement.